# Compilation of Documents for Temporary Residence Visa

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens

Just a final review of Documents I have at this point to prove ties to home country. Just needed some form of clarification then I can upload and submit for Canadian TRV (Temporary Residence Visa) Here is an overview of the documents I have. Please should there be any other documents I should add kindly let me know

- Registered Business name with Corporate affairs Commission Certificate and Bank Statements (I do recieve funds inside my account which bears my personal name for the Business. I use this account for the small business which I run) I have a sworn affidavit in this case too confirming the authenticity of the document from a court of Justice here in Nigeria.
- The office i currently work in, I have the ID card as well as the Offer letters and a stamped Leave approval confirmation letter from my Project Lead.
- Attached Payslips (For three months) as well as Bank Statements for the Full-Time job i do (in order to tally with the information I provided) (6 months).
- Attached copies of Landed properties which I have in my name.
- Attached copies of round trip travel Ticket confirmation (Flight ticket Confirmation) and hotel reservation confirmation for the stipulated days as well.
- Travel trips i made to some parts of West Africa, I did not have the stamps inside my travel Document (Passport) but as someone said its not mandatory as well, but i think in detail, i would make an explanatory note to detail that fact clearly.

Now here is the big question, with all these I have here are there anything I appear to be missing out which could lead to denial for Canadian visas? I do need to be quite sure before making any submission.

As usual, I am from Nigeria.